# How do I show a directory path in a textbox when selected by the user?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

First, I am using Visual Studio 2013 and coding in C# to develop a Windows Form Application.  I have added the "System.IO" namespace.

I need to show a directory path in a textbox when selected by the user.
The code works correctly to where the user selects a folder from a popup
and presses the OK button, which then displays the number of files within 
that folder -- but the folder path does NOT get displayed as I desired.

Code looks like this:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // This event handler was created by clicking the button in the application GUI.
        //
        DialogResult button1_Click = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (button1_Click == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //
            // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
            // A message pops up and identifies the number of files found within that folder.
            //
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
        }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path;
        path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        // folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog(); // NOT SURE ABOUT USING THIS!
        textBox1.Text = path;
    }
```

Comment: dont try that in TextChanged - that event will fire as they type each character assuring that you need to add error handling for partially typed input

Comment: Thanks.  I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

You could just add this to the end of your `button1_Click` method (inside the `if` block):

```
textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```